How to fix buffer overrun from char array variable?
Im getting runtime error code #2 buffer overrun from pword char array. Any tips to help resolve isuue.
//Write a program to determine whether or not an entered 
//password is valid.Valid passwords consist of 10 characters,
//4 of which must be letters and the other 6 digits.
//The letters and digits can be arranged in any order.
//Only lowercase letters are allowed for valid passwords.
//Hints: use islower, isalpha, isdigit, and strlen.

#include<iostream>
#include<cctype>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int Size = 10;
    char pword[Size];
    int count=0;
    int totall = 0;
    int totaln = 0;
    bool state = NULL;

    while(state != true) 
    {
    
        cout << "Enter a password up to 10 characters: " << endl;
        cin >> pword;

        int psize = strlen(pword);
        totall = 0;
        totaln = 0;
        while (pword[count] != '\0')

        {
            if (isalpha(pword[count]))
            {
                totall += 1;
            }

            if (isdigit(pword[count]))
            {
                totaln += 1;
            }
            count++;
        }
        if (totall > 4 || totaln > 6)
        {
            cout << " Error! Only enter 4 characters and 6 digits." << endl;
            state = false;
        }
        else
        {
            state = true;
        }
        count = 0;
        while(pword[count]!='\0')
        {
            if (!islower(pword[count]))
            {
                if (!isdigit(pword[count]))
                {
                    cout << "Error all characters must be lowercase!" << endl;
                    state = false;
                }
            }  
            count++;
        }

     
    }
   
        cout << "The password you entered is: " << pword << endl;
        cout << "The number of lower case letters in the password is " << totall << endl;
        cout << "The number of digits in the password is " << totaln << endl;
      
        return 0;
}

I tried dynamically allocating the char array by :
pword[Size]= (char*)malloc(sizeof(char))={};


failed though so I reverted the code back. I'm attempting to make a space on the heap for the char array indices 0-10 with null terminating character at 10 index. Looking at malloc though I don't see how I can make the array longer than a char this way?
The exact error message is "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'pword' was corrupted." it occurs only when an incorrect password is entered then at completion the error occurs.

If you're using C++, don't use malloc. Use new instead. But don't do that either when things like std::vector exist.

Just use a std::string.

It's unlikely that you get a stack overflow from a tiny array of size 10.

int pword[10]; isn't big enough for a 10 character password. It doesn't allow for a null terminator. It is not on the heap. Its highest valid index is 9, not 10. And yes, since you are using C++. use std:string instead.

@crhis no use types like std::string and std::vector first. new/delete should only be used inside data structure classes (if at all).

Use std::string input; std::cin >> input; and then write a function bool validate(const std::string& input). This is C++ so you hardly ever should have to use new/delete (and don't use malloc/free at all)

Check the error message again and make sure it's not saying stack buffer overflow.

Where are you learning C++ when you first thought is to use an array, and your second thought is to use malloc? Any experienced C++ programmer is going to use a std::string for the password.

bool state = NULL; should be bool state = false; This code is very strange.

It's a school assignment and there is a layout provided so I'm just following it. Also good catch int pword[Size] was meant to be char pword[Size]. No can't use string instructions say to make a char array.

Side note: the most recent C++ Standard revisions remove the >> to pointer-to-character-type overloads because they're so easily overflowed and a huge source of bugs. In its place you'll find >> overloads that take arrays of character types, infers the sizes of the arrays, and uses those sizes to prevent overflows. Documentation link for details

The main fix is to change this declaration:
int pword[Size];

To simply this:
string pword;

No more buffer overrun possibilities.  Also bool state = NULL; doesn't sound like something that should compile, but perhaps the NULL coerces to false.
Some minor improvements to the code:
int main()
{
    string pword;
    int totall = 0;
    int totaln = 0;
    int isAllLowercase = true;
    bool state = false;

    while(state != true) 
    {
        cout << "Enter a password up to 10 characters: " << endl;
        cin >> pword;

        totall = 0;
        totaln = 0;
        isAllLowercase = true;

        for (char c : pword)
        {
            if (isalpha(c))
            {
                totall += 1;
            }

            if (isdigit(c))
            {
                totaln += 1;
            }
            isAllLowerCase = isAllLowerCase && (islower(c) || isdigit(c));
        }
        if (totall > 4 || totaln > 6)
        {
            cout << " Error! Only enter 4 characters and 6 digits." << endl;
        }
        else if (!isAllLowerCase)
        {
            cout << "Error all characters must be lowercase!" << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            state = true;
        }
    }
   
    cout << "The password you entered is: " << pword << endl;
    cout << "The number of lower case letters in the password is " << totall << endl;
    cout << "The number of digits in the password is " << totaln << endl;
      
    return 0;
}


This would work and was my first thought but the instructor wants us to use a char array. I'm not sure how to resolve the stack corruption around the variable pword?

The original problem in your code is that if the user types 10 chars, it will write 11 to the array.  That's because it will always want to append a \0 to the end.  So just declare Size to be 1000.

nice thank you forgot about space for the null terminator.
